# Variables Getting Mixed Up

Tags: php, codeigniter

OK, I went through a database tutorial and eventually ended up with the following:

```
function index() {
    $this->load->model('dataModel');

    $data['rows'] = $this->dataModel->getAll();     
    $data = array('title' => 'NKADD Calendar of Events', 'main_content' => 'pages/contact');
    $this->load->view('template/main', $data);

}
```

I am getting errors and I believe it has something to do with the $data array/variable getting confused, but I'm not sure how to fix it!

This is the view page, btw

```
foreach ($rows as $r) {
    echo '<h1>' . $r->title . '</h1>';
}
```

An error is reached when viewing the page

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: rows
Filename: pages/contact.php
```

Any Assitance?

Comment: Please share the errors as well. Error messages help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, error is

    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: rows

Filename: pages/contact.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need not add to `$data` array, array of variables, but to do something like this:

```
$data = array(
    'rows'    => $this->dataModel->getAll(),
    'title'   => 'Your title',
    'main_content'    => 'your main content value',
);
```

Or adding elements to array, as:

```
$data['title'] = 'Your title';
// so on
```

This way you can access $title and $rows, and other vars in template.

Comment: This did the trick... I see what it was I was not understanding... thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 3):

You mixed up $data['rows']="something" and $data="something", use

```
$data['rows'] = $this->dataModel->getAll();     
$data[] = array('title' => 'NKADD Calendar of Events', 'main_content' => 'pages/contact');
```

By assigning $data=array('....') at the second line you have assigned new data to the $data, so old values has gone.

Try something like this in your model

```
//foreach($q->result() as $row)                                                       
//{ 
//$data[] = $row; 
//} 
//return $data; 
return $q->result();
```

Comment: This still produced an error... not sure why as looks right and I understand what I was doing wrong. The error was A PHP Error was encountered, Severity: Notice, Message: Undefined variable: main_content, Filename: template/main.php, Line Number: 37

Comment: According to my example above your main_content variable is in another array. $data[0]['main_content']. Can you give me your code where you are trying to get the variable main_content.

Comment: Here is the dataModel:
`class Datamodel extends CI_Model {
 
 function getAll() {
  $q = $this->db->get('data');
  
  if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
   foreach($q->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
   }
   return $data;
  }
 }
}`


The controller (included working code from above answer)
`class Contact extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
  $this->load->model('dataModel');
  
  $data = array('rows' => $this->dataModel->getAll(), 'title' => 'NKADD Calendar of Events', 'main_content' => 'pages/contact');
  $this->load->view('template/main', $data);
 }
}`

Comment: Here is the view
`<?php
 foreach ($rows as $r) {
  echo '<h1>' . $r->title . '</h1>';
 }
 ?>`

Comment: Try something like this in your model //foreach($q->result() as $row) 
     //{ 
      //$data[] = $row; 
     //} 
     //return $data; 
     return $q->result();

Comment: $data['rows'] contains an array, you should loop it. $data['title'] is an element of data array, $data['main_content'] is an element of data array. try to print_r($data); in your view, you can see everything.